# Sending sms with php link

Tags: php, laravel, sms

Is there a way I can embed a URL link i.e. Google in an SMS message send through [myphonenumber]@txt.att.net ? And I want to add some parameters in the URL. The link shows up as un-clickable plain text in the SMS with html tag. The html tag appears in the SMS. I want to hide or embed html codes. I pass the parameters with this url in my Controler. When sending sms, I found out the html codes are including in the sms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed URL Link in SMS via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096212/embed-url-link-in-sms-via-php)

Comment: Similar problem but I want to know more details. Any more ideas?

Comment: What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: I added some modifications in my questions. Please check it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the HTML tags. I think to some degree you will have to rely on the actual device to detect text as a clickable link.

Comment: According to this, SMS is text only, you cannot embed html tags. https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/63

Comment: When I removed the html tags, it works. Any ideas to add only html url text in the sms. I tested the shorten url but I does not support dynamic parameters in the url.

Comment: If you have parameters, your best bet is to use the full URL, no shorteners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS is a text-only medium that does not interpret HTML tags on its own. Depending on the receiving device, it may detect a hyperlink in the message, but there is no way to embed it as an

```
<a href>
```

tag

github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/63